# Get selected TreeViewItem in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate, treeviewitem

I want make TreeView with editable nodes. I googled this good, as I think, article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31592/Editable-TextBlock-in-WPF-for-In-place-Editing

But I have a problems. My TreeView formed dinamically, not statically as in the arcticle. Like that

```
    <TreeView Name="_packageTreeView" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding PackageExtendedList}">
         <TreeView.InputBindings>
             <KeyBinding Key="C" Command="{Binding *TestCommand*}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
         </TreeView.InputBindings>
         <i:Interaction.Triggers>
             <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
                 <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PackageTreeItemChangeCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=_packageTreeView, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
             </i:EventTrigger>
         </i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
             <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                 <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
             </Style>
         </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
         <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
             <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MasterBuisnessLogic:RootDocPackage}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Childs}">
                 <Grid>
                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                         <ColumnDefinition>
                         </ColumnDefinition>
                         <ColumnDefinition>
                         </ColumnDefinition>
                     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="/Resources/DocGroup.png"></Image>
                    <Etb:EditableTextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></Etb:EditableTextBlock>
                 </Grid> 
             </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
         </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
     </TreeView>
```

*PackageExtendedList* - List of DocPackageExtended.

So, first question - how can I get TreeViewItem instance in TestCommand? Not instance *DocPackageExtended* class! I want to get instance selected *TreeViewItem* like in the article.

And second question - After I get instance *TreeViewItem*, how can I get *EditableTextBlock* from the TreeView item's DataTemplate.

**added answer**

I already tried it. Cause in MVVM ViewModel cannot has any link to View object like TreeView, I make handler in code-behind, like that

```
private void TreeViewItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Already have TreeViewItem instance without of ItemContainerGenerator help
    var tvi = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;

    if (tvi == null)
        return;

    var etb = VisualTreeLib.VisualTreeLib.GetVisualChild<EditableTextBlock>(tvi);
    if (etb == null)
        return;

    // Do what I want
    etb.IsEditable = true;
}
```

Unfortunately, this has no any affect :(

I also tried that approach, but also failed.

in DocPackageExtended type I define property

```
public bool IsEditable
{
    get { return _isEditable; }
    set
    {
        _isEditable = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsEditable"));
    }
}
```

than change in XAML:

```
<Etb:EditableTextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" *IsEditable="{Binding Path=IsEditable}"*/>
```

and in ViewModel

```
private void TestCommandMethod(object obj)
{
    var dpe = obj as DocPackageExtended;
    if (dpe == null)
       return;
    dpe.IsEditable = true;
}
```

Doesn't work too :(
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First question: Since it seems that you can select multiple entries, you need to filter all selected entries in TestCommand's executed method:

```
IEnumerable<DocPackageExtended> selectedEntries = PackageExtendedList.Where(d => d.IsSelected);
```

If multiple selection is disabled, you could bind the TreeView's selected item to a property in your VM and access this property in TestCommand's method.

Second question: You get the dataitem's container through `var container = YourTreeViewInstance.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dataInstance);`. Now you have to go through this container with the help of the [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) until it finds a control of type `EditableTextBlock`. But I wouldn't do this in a ViewModel, rather in a helper-class or with the help of attached properties.

EDIT: You're binding the IsEditable property of the instances in the `Childs` property of your `DocPackageExtended` class to your EditableTextBox, but in your `TestCommandMethod` you're manipulating the `IsEditable`property of a DocPackageExtended instance directly. You could do the following:

```
private void TestCommandMethod(object obj)
{
    var dpe = obj as DocPackageExtended;
    if (dpe == null)
       return;
    dpe.IsEditable = true;
    foreach (RootDocPackage rdp in dpe.Childs)
    {
        rdp.IsEditable = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added answer to first post to be able format code, look.
How u make grey background in text? Cannot find.

Comment: I assume the CommandParameter in your TestCommand is the `ViewModel` itself and not a `DocPackageExtended`-instance, so the conversation returns null all the time. If thats the case, have a look at my edit.

Comment: CommandParameter has correct type object (DocPackageExtended), checked under debugger. No multiselection allowed.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem treeViewItemFound = GetItem(MyTreeview, MyTreeview.SelectedItem);
        ContentPresenter header = treeViewItemFound.Template.FindName("PART_Header", treeViewItemFound) as ContentPresenter;
        if (header != null)
        {
            TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)header.ContentTemplate.FindName("MyTextBox", header);
        }
    }

    public TreeViewItem GetItem(ItemsControl container, object itemToSelect)
    {
        foreach (object item in container.Items)
        {
            if (item == itemToSelect)
            {
                return (TreeViewItem)container.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
            }
            else
            {
                ItemsControl itemContainer = (ItemsControl)container.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
                if (itemContainer.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    TreeViewItem treeViewItemFound = GetItem(itemContainer, itemToSelect);
                    if (treeViewItemFound != null)
                        return treeViewItemFound;
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```